# htaccess Force SSL if certain file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have the following mod rewrite code that forces SSL on my website:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have to edit the htaccess file if I want to turn this off or on. So what I am thinking is to have a file for example called ssl_on stored in a certain path of the server and if the file ssl_on exists then this rule applies and if the file doesn't exist then the rule shouldnt apply. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ssl_on -f
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

`-f` condition will ensure that rule will fire only when `ssl_on` file exists in website root. Also better to use `R=302` instead of `R=301` to avoid permanent redirects caching in browser.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond):

> One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.

So going by this, you could have before (or after) your current `RewriteCond` line a new `RewriteCond` line:

```
RewriteCond <HTTPS_TOGGLE_FILE_PATH> -f
```

And because both rules need to be true in order for the Rule to be matched, the file would have to exist before the 301 header would be issued.

Note that the rules for caching 301 headers in browsers are convoluted- a lot of them cache the redirection indefinitely. So if you want this to truly be toggleable (e.g. browsers that have accessed the site via HTTP when the redirection is enabled then accessing the site via HTTP when it is disabled) then a 302 would be preferable.